# In C assigning value to a field inside structure is resulting in "expected a ';'" error

Tags: c, windows, structure

I have assigned values to a fields in a structure. This resulted in multiple errors.

```
typedef struct t_queue {
int head = 0;
int tail = 0;
int maxSize = 0;
int size = 0;
SOCKET* queue = NULL;
}Queue;

typedef struct t_threadData {
int topicID;

bool isEngineActive = FALSE;
bool isServerActive = TRUE;
int numberOfConnectedSubs = 0;

Queue* queue;

HANDLE PublisherReady;
HANDLE ThreadReady;
HANDLE BarrierOK;
CRITICAL_SECTION Critical_Section;

int NumberOfThreadsWaiting = 0;
SOCKET sockets[NUMBER_OF_SUBSCRIBERS];

}ThreadData;
```

Errors are:

1. E0065 expected a ';'
2. E0020 identifier "bool" is undefined

I'm working in C on Windows 10 using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: Structure in C cannot be used like that. Use C++11 or later if you want to do that.

Comment: That's a definition of a struct, it just describes the fields, their types and order within the structure, you cannot assign anything to them.

Comment: I understand. Thank you

Comment: To use `bool` in C, add [`#include <stdbool.h>`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/stdbool.h.0p.html).

Answer (score 0):

Read [Modern C](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). If you compile with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to compile your code. Read also the documentation of your C compiler, and enable all warnings in it. Read also the documentation of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/))

You should code:

```
typedef struct t_queue {
  int head;
  int tail;
  int maxSize;
  int size;
  SOCKET* queue;
}  Queue;
```

BTW, your field names are confusing. Since `head` and `tail` suggests a [doubly-linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list). Then they should be pointers!

Consider also using the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) -or [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/)- on your project.

Take inspiration from the source code of some existing open source software coded in C (like [Glib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib), [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/), [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), etc...)